# compare datetime with DateField for equivalency?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
import datetime as dt 
dt.datetime.strptime( '2000', '%Y' )
```

creates  a date object, which I can put into a django `models.DateField( )`

but, once the DateField is committed to the database, I am not able to check for equality with an equivalent source datetime object:

```
>>> dt.datetime.strptime( '2000', '%Y' ) == myRecalledDbObj.dateFieldVal
False
```

and printing them reveals:

```
1961-12-23 00:00:00
1961-12-23
```

So... how to compare for equivalency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a datetime to a date. These will never be equal. Try calling the date method on your datetime to compare it to the DateField in django, or alternatively, switch your model to use a DateTimeField.

```
dt.datetime.strptime('2000', '%Y').date() == myRecalledDbObj.dateFieldVal
```